# Can´t import tags from svn to git

Tags: git, svn

i´ve already migrated (some time ago) several svn and mercurial repos to git. But now i have a svn repo which makes some problems in the tag area.

1. I can easily download a svn repo with

   git svn clone --stdlayout http://user@my.host.xx/svn/repo00

   and i get a repo on my local disk. Under this new directory "repo00"
   there are the directories from the old repos living.
2. After import from svn i do the following steps:
3. Create new git repo on GitLab

   - cd repo00
   - git remote add origin git@gitlab.xx:user/newgitrepo.git
   - git add .
   - git commit -m "Initial commit"
   - git push -u origin master  --tags

This way i could migrate the svn directory. 
Sometimes the tags where not transfered, then i did the following in a batch (the tags i fetched from the git config directory: "*.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags/*"):

```
- git checkout -b tag4811 tag4811
- git commit -m'Initial Commit tag4811'
- git tag -a tag4811 -m'tag4811'
- git push -u origin master
```

(I could do the same with the branches in a batch where i fetched the branches and migrated them.) But now i have a problem, although i can download the svn directory and upload it nicely, i have problems in migrating the tags. As said, they are lying in the "*.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags/*" but when i do the above described procedure, it says, already at the first tag an checkout:
   **fatal: 'tag4811' is not a commit and a branch 'tag4811' cannot be created from it**

It seems that i can´t create or migrate the tag although it is listed in the directory. Does someone know how to migrate the tags?
(I´ve already read other answers on this site but they were not helpfull and "svn2git" is somehow opaque because of the "rules")

regards

Comment: Didn´t manage to import the tags. Is there a method to create/import the tags manually? In the svn directory there are "branches", "tags" and "trunk" directory so they are all obviously there. Is it possible to migrate them manually?

Answer (score 0):

`git svn` requires a lot of pre- and post-processing.

```
# Convert branches and tags

# See http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/08/converting-from-svn-to-git.html

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/svn |
   sed 's#svn/##' | grep -v '^tags' |
      while read aBranch; do git branch $aBranch svn/$aBranch || exit 1; done

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/svn/tags/ |
while read tag; do
    GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%ad\" \"$tag\"`" \
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%ce\" \"$tag\"`" \
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%cn\" \"$tag\"`" \
    git tag -a -m "`git for-each-ref --format=\"%(contents)\" \"$tag\"`" \
        "`echo \"$tag\" | sed 's#svn/tags/##'`" "$tag" || exit 1
done
```

See my script [`svn2git`](http://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=tree;f=svn) (no, it's not that well-known svn2git).

Comment: thank you. But if you look at your script you will see that your commands are the same i gave in my description. It will not work either if the commands are called from a script. The command in question, which i described which is failing is: git checkout -b tag4811 tag4811 which isn´t working. Your command "git branch $aBranch svn/$aBranch wouldn´t work either (besides it would have the wrong directory). Regards

Comment: It's because I use `--prefix=svn/` in `git svn clone`.